# What is the effect of preserving Angular Router query parameters?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-router

Per [this article](https://alligator.io/angular/query-parameters/) with Angular it's possible to preserve query parameters like this:

```
goUsers() {
  this.router.navigate(['/users'], { queryParamsHandling: 'preserve' 
   });
}
```

I'm looking for a practical examples that shows why we might want to do this?

Comment: You could for example implement filtering and memorize it with query-params. If you didn't preserve query params, they'd get lost on re-route.

Comment: I'm not sure what memorize it with query parameters means?  A practical example would go a long way here.

Answer (score 1):

If you look into the definition for [queryParamsHandling](https://angular.io/api/router/NavigationExtras#queryParamsHandling) (not much is given there), it is to handle next navigation.

The practical example would be if you want to make your app stateless. So it will help you no to maintain the selections made on web page to be maintained. For example on shopping or travelling site, they store the choices selected in query parameters as even site goes down or you reload the page the choices selected still persist.

Second would be easier bookmarking so when you bookmark the page with given selections, you can easily open it next time or even forward this link to anyone without specifying the selections that you choose for the result.

For client-side application, its a good way to store state at given pageview and when you move forward or backward in browser history your selection will persist. It will be helpful for user as each time they don't have to update their choices.

Comment: Are you able to illustrate with some hello world like code that illustrates what happens over a sequence of events?

Comment: For example the article navigates to users and sets query params handling to to preserve, but it's still not clear to me what effect this has ... in other words what the difference between preserve or no preserve ...

Comment: in article an example is given how to do that if you are moving across pages or maybe on user page based on previous page action you want to display additional info on user profile. For second Q, if you don't put the preserve the params will lost on subsequent navigation action ( as mentioned in article only). It depends if you want to use selections of this page on other page.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you are at:

```
http://localhost:4200/heros?hero=jack
```

And you want to move to the crisis center but keep `jack` as the hero, so that you can match `jack` up to a crisis.

```
goCrises() {
  this.router.navigate(['/crises-center'], { queryParamsHandling: 'preserve' 
  });
}
```

This changes the URL to `http://localhost:4200/crises-center?hero=jack` and that component can retrieve the `hero` parameter via `ActivateRoute` and match up the hero to a crises.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this to preserve the lang queryparam.

According to Google's guidelines, one url must match a specific content. So storing the language in localStorage is not recommended.